# Java - ActionListeners give data to methods

Tags: java, string

I have an actionlistener that takes data from a group of buttons (I know, separating them into one per button is next, just wait...)

I want it to call a "reveal" method, that changes the ImageIcon of those buttons. To know what icon to change it to, "reveal" has to be able to access a String array. This String array is created in a method in the same class as reveal, passed and processed in another class, and then returned to a different method in the same class as reveal.

How can I pass the String array to the reveal function? I've tried making the string array public at the top of the class it's created in. However, it appears that it's not returned correctly and when reveal tries to access it all the values are null.

Comment: For a runnable example demonstrating your problem? Sorry, it's the weekend and my brain has shut off, so trying to read your explanation just hurts :(

Comment: it's really hard trying to imagine this in my head. Actually I lied, I don't feel like performing such mentally intensive exercise involving spatial awareness and abstract thinking, can you please write some code you've tried?

Comment: Terribly confusing. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it would be great to see actual code, but I believe I understand what is happening here.  First, let me establish some names, for clarity.  Let class A be the class that owns the String array (and has the reveal function).  Let class B be the class that does the processing on the String array.

When you pass the String array off to the class B for processing, you just need to make sure of one of two things:

1) If you are returning a String array from that function, make sure you use it to set the value of the String array within class A, from whatever function class A uses to call the class B processing function.

```
// from class A
private String[] stringsToHealAllAils;
...
public void aFunctionThatNeedsProcessingWithDiscriminatingTaste()
{
    // instance of class B is called b
    stringsToHealAllAils = b.processThingy( stringsToHealAllAils );
}
```

In this case, the processing function in class B will need to return a brand new String array based on the String array from A.  And Class A's function will need to replace the value of the String array with the return value of the processing function.

or

2) If you are modifying the String array from class A within the processing function owned by class B (see sample code below)

```
public void processThingy( String[] thatLegendaryArray )
{
    // some amazing processing here
    thatLegendaryArray[superSpecialIndex] = someOtherVerySpecialString;
}
```

that is to say that you are probably populating the array within class B's processing function.  This is OK as well, but as the sample code suggests, you won't need to set the value of the String array from within class A (ala example 1).

What I am saying is, I think that you are failing to handle your String array properly if the reveal function is getting a pile of null.  If this doesn't help, then be sure to post some code showing more explicitly what you're doing.  I am confident that the solution is at hand.